# EmptyDataError No columns to parse from file

Tags: python, pandas

[i am getting the error "EmptyDataError No columns to parse from file" when i am reading the data from csv file to json file...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o4ze.png)

i want to insert the data from csv file to json file

Comment: How your merged csv looks like? can copy and post the sample tables data. or snapshot of the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

replace "/" to "\" in you path variable

Comment: Noooo. Its not working. Iam getting the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

find error and used "delim_whitespace=True" in read_csv

Comment: no.. its not working